# Intellij IDEA on fedora

Tags: java, intellij-idea, fedora

I don't can run intellij IDEA on fedora MATE 22.

Error:

```
tools.jar' seems to be not in idea classpath.
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.
```

Comment: Do you have JAVA_HOME set to the Java JDK?

Comment: I don't know, how to watch ?

Comment: You must be able to run the "javac" command for IntelliJ to work.

Comment: @Hooli here are some steps to install and configure Java JDK on your machine: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-install-java-jdk-on-fedora-core-linux/

Answer (score 2):

fedora comes with native package support for openjdk.  but to run intellij idea without problems on fedora, you really need to use the jdk from oracle (sun), not openjdk.  that is what i was told by intellij. empirically, they've been right.

Answer (score 2):

As you've been told, install the official JDK from Oracle. Then run in the terminal:

```
alternatives --config java
```

And choose the official JDK.

Answer (score 0):

First check if you have installed a JDK on you system.

If not download and install it.

Second verify that the JAVA_HOME variable is set and pointing to JDK root?